# Attendance Data as per clock IN/OUT Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-and-attendance

I am trying to develop an attendance application which calculates the shift details as per the Clock IN OUT Data , the following are the table details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INOUTData](
    EmpID VARCHAR(10),
    CLockDate Date  NULL,
    [INTIME]  Time NULL,
    [OUTTIME]  Time NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INOUTData (   EmpID,   CLockDate,   [INTIME], [OUTTIME]  ) VALUES
(  'E1',   '28-Jan-2014', '07:50:00',  '10:15:00' ),
(  'E1',   '28-Jan-2014', '10:25:00',  '12:15:00' ),
(  'E1',   '28-Jan-2014', '17:15:00',  '20:55:00' ),

(  'E2',   '28-Jan-2014', '08:30:00',  NULL ),  -- First Session OUT punch missed
(  'E2',   '28-Jan-2014', '16:15:00',  '21:55:00' ),

(  'E3',   '28-Jan-2014', NULL,  '11:34:00' ),  -- First Session IN punch missed
(  'E3',   '28-Jan-2014', '16:15:00',  '19:55:00' ),
(  'E3',   '28-Jan-2014', '20:05:00',  '21:55:00' ),

(  'E4',   '28-Jan-2014', '08:30:00',  '11:34:00' ), 
(  'E4',   '28-Jan-2014', NULL,  '21:55:00' ), -- Second Session IN punch missed

(  'E5',   '28-Jan-2014', '10:35:00',  '13:44:00' ), 
(  'E5',   '28-Jan-2014',  '18:55:00' , NULL ) -- Second Session OUT punch missed
```

And `ShiftDetails`:

```
Create Table ShiftDetails
(
    ShiftId INT ,
    ShiftName VARCHAR(20),
    Session1StartTime  TIme ,
    Session1EndTime  TIme ,
    Session2StartTime  TIme ,
    Session2EndTime TIme 
)

Insert into ShiftDetails values
(1,'Break Shift', '08:00:00', '12:00:00', '17:00:00', '21:00:00'),
(2,'Break Shift2', '10:00:00', '14:00:00', '19:00:00', '23:00:00')
```

I am trying to get the data as follows combining these two tables

```
EMpID   ClockDate       Session1StartTime   Session1EndTime     ActualSession1StartTime     ActualSession1EndTime   Session2StartTime   Session2EndTime     ActualSession2StartTime     ActualSession2EndTime 
E1      28-Jan-2014     08:00:00            12:00:00            07:50:00        12:15:00        17:00:00    21:00:00            17:15:00         20:55:00                                       
E2      28-Jan-2014     08:00:00            12:00:00            08:30:00        NULL            17:00:00    21:00:00            16:15:00                    21:55:00                                            
E3      28-Jan-2014     08:00:00            12:00:00            NULL                11:34:00        17:00:00    21:00:00            16:15:00           21:55:00                                             
E4      28-Jan-2014     08:00:00            12:00:00            08:30:00             11:34:00       17:00:00    21:00:00            NULL           21:55:00                                             
E5      28-Jan-2014     10:00:00            14:00:00            10:35:00        14:44:00        19:00:00    23:00:00            18:55:00           NULL
```

kindly give suggestions how to achieve in an effective way, right now i am using a stored procedure which traverses through each record and does the job.

Is there any way to do it with Pivot, or queries instead of cursors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you ever have employees stay after midnight, it would be far better to model the `in` and `out` as just a pair of `datetime2` values (and not have a separate `ClockDate` column)

Comment: break shifts are only for single day. it wont be for the next day